# Import functions from another js file. Javascript

Tags: javascript, import

I have a question about including a file in javascript. 
I have a very simple example:

```
--> index.html
--> models
      --> course.js
      --> student.js
```

course.js:

```
function Course() {
    this.id = '';
    this.name = '';
}
```

A student has a course property. like this:

```
import './course';

function Student() {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.course = new Course();
}
```

and the index.html is like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./models/student.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
        </div>
        <script>
        window.onload= function() {
            var x = new Student();
            x.course.id = 1;
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = x.course.id;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am getting an error on the line "var x = new Student();":

> Student is not defined

When I remove the import from Student, I don't receive the error anymore.
I have tried to use (require, import, include, create a custom function, export) and none has worked for me.

Anybody knows why? and how to fix that?

P.S. the path is correct, it comes from the autocomplete in VS Code

Comment: May I link to the docs for now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: I don't think he has an issue with imports, he has an issue with the environment he's trying to run it in. Browsers don't handle import by default.

Comment: Did you watch it in browser's F12 dev tools window?

Comment: Browsers doesn't support them yet. May be in future. Check this link for more info https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how-do-you-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: himm, I will investigate it.

Comment: Also this: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

Comment: I have tried those solutions and none of them has worked for me!

Comment: @SamySammour Did you miss my answer? My solution works on Firefox, even in the `file:///` environment.

Comment: @ChrisG That article is out of date. You can now use ES6 modules in browsers, they just have to use the "module" type.

Comment: @samanime Do you guys not see the answer I provided? It's fully tested, working code.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The following works for me in Firefox and Chrome. In Firefox it even works from `file:///`

> models/course.js

```
export function Course() {
    this.id = '';
    this.name = '';
};
```

> models/student.js

```
import { Course } from './course.js';

export function Student() {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.course = new Course();
};
```

> index.html

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
<script type="module">
    import { Student } from './models/student.js';

    window.onload = function () {
        var x = new Student();
        x.course.id = 1;
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = x.course.id;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did not work unfortunately, throughs: Access to Script at 'file:///........./models/student.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @SamySammour That's what I get in Chrome, it does work in Firefox though. Doesn't matter; in production you'll be serving the files anyway (which makes that error disappear). This is how to implement the current state of module support for browsers, so it's the answer to your question, whether it works for you or not ;)

Comment: It did not work on Firefox as well. It throughs an exception "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol." and no output on the screen

Comment: If you see a `1`, it worked. The exception is unrelated and caused by your not having `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your `<head>`.

Comment: I have mentioned that there was no Output, the screen was empty. Why javascript has to be so complicated

Comment: Because module support is experimental. I put my example online: https://khrismuc.github.io/ Source here: https://github.com/khrismuc/khrismuc.github.io Does that work for you?

Comment: Still nothing, No browser has shown a value. Edge, Firefox, Chrome, IE. Still empty page

Comment: In Firefox you need to enable `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` in about:config, like it says in the article. In Chrome it works out of the box. Testing Edge right now. ... Yep, works fine in Edge. Just to be clear, it's a blank page with a small `1` in the top left corner.

Comment: Done, I have hosted in on the local IIS and it works! Thanks
P.S: also in chrome

Comment: Ooh, I checked other browsers. Apparently it has worked only on chrome

Comment: @SamySammour Yes, like I said, this is experimental technology right now and not widely supported. It does work for me in Edge, and in Firefox after enabling the option though. See my comment above.

Comment: It is possible improve the proposed design including `models_inlcude.js` in `models` folder. The file imports all needed models and in HTML file only add `<script type="module" language="javascript" src="models/models_inlcude.js"></script>` in `<head>` tag. Using this way you avoid add extra script code in your HTML code

Comment: @SamySammour . Please try to use a live server for this, you won't get CORS error

Answer (score 23):

You can try as follows:

```
//------ js/functions.js ------
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}

//------ js/main.js ------
import { square, diag } from './functions.js';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

You can also import completely:

```
//------ js/main.js ------
import * as lib from './functions.js';
console.log(lib.square(11)); // 121
console.log(lib.diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

Normally we use `./fileName.js` for importing own `js file/module` and `fileName.js` is used for importing `package/library` module

When you will include the main.js file to your webpage you must set the type="module" attribute as follows:

```
<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

For more details please check [ES6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

Comment: Adding  `type="module"` is important in case of Qunit's html.

Answer (score 9):

By default, scripts can't handle imports like that directly. You're probably getting another error about not being able to get Course or not doing the import.

If you add `type="module"` to your `<script>` tag, and change the import to `./course.js` (because browsers won't auto-append the .js portion), then the browser will pull down course for you and it'll probably work.

```
import './course.js';

function Student() {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.course = new Course();
}
```

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./models/student.js" type="module"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
        </div>
        <script>
        window.onload= function() {
            var x = new Student();
            x.course.id = 1;
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = x.course.id;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

If you're serving files over `file://`, it likely won't work. Some IDEs have a way to run a quick sever.

You can also write a quick `express` server to serve your files (install Node if you don't have it):

```
//package.json
{
  "scripts": { "start": "node server" },
  "dependencies": { "express": "latest" }
}

// server/index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('PATH_TO_YOUR_FILES_HERE');
app.listen(8000);
```

With those two files, run `npm install`, then `npm start` and you'll have a server running over `http://localhost:8000` which should point to your files.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work and now it throws an extra exception. " Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: If you're seeing that, that's a cross-origin exception. Are you running it from the `file://` protocol or  `http://`? If you're running it from `file://`, you're going to have a tough time.

Comment: file:// . What to do then? how to fix that?

Comment: The best way is to use some sort of server to serve them over `localhost`. Some IDEs have them built-in. You can also write a quick `express` server in just a few lines. I'll give you an example in my answer.

Comment: I cannot use any server.

Answer (score 6):

```
//In module.js add below code

export function multiply() {
    return 2 * 3;
}
```

// Consume the module in calc.js

```
import { multiply } from './modules.js';

const result = multiply();

console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
```

// Module.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Module</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="module" src="./calc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its a design pattern same code can be found below, please use a live server to test it else you will get CORS error

https://github.com/rohan12patil/JSDesignPatterns/tree/master/Structural%20Patterns/module