# Javascript Deactivate some lines in a script

Tags: javascript, function

In a website, there is a js file like:

```
<script src="/somescript.js"></script>
```

somescript.js includes:

```
<script> 
 function hi(){alert('Hi');} 
 function sup(){alert('Sup!');} 
 hi();
 sup();    
</script>
```

When I enter the index page, my browser automatically runs the function `hi()`

How can I prevent browser to run the function `hi()` or change it into something i want.

Website is not mine.

Thanks

Comment: Is this your website?

Comment: There is no chance that browser launch a function by itself. You must have a <script>hi()</script> somewhere in index page

Comment: no its not my website.

Comment: sorry forgot to add hi();

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. You might be able to write a browser extension that prevents loading `somescript.js` entirely, but I don't think it can selectively deactivate parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

This will call the functions, the need to be removed from the script if you don't want them run.

```
 hi();
 sup();
```

You can also specify functions as exports and import them [as show in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211891/import-functions-from-another-js-file-javascript).

Comment: He can't change the script, it's not his website.