# Importing functions from other file

Tags: javascript

I have a two Javascript files both having some functions. I want to access functions from one file into another. How can I do it without webpack or any other module bundler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import functions from another js file. Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211891/import-functions-from-another-js-file-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In the file (methods.js) you have the method you want to export:

```
    export function Example() {
        return “value”
    }
```

Then in the file where you will import the method:

```
    import Example from ‘./methods.js’;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function cannot be called unless it was defined in the same file or one loaded before the attempt to call it.

A function cannot be called unless it is in the same or greater scope, then the one trying to call it.

Suppose you declare a function `function1()` in One.js, and then in Two.js you can just have `function1();`

#### One.js

```
function function1 () {
    alert('Test');
}
```

#### Two.js

```
function1 ();
```

#### Test.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="One.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Two.js"></script>
```