# share code between ES module and node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I've written ES module which imports other modules and exports some stuff.
Now I want to use the same module in Node.  (share the same file)

Is there any universal way how to deal with differences e.g. "import" vs "require" and "export" vs "exports"?
I want solution without browserify or webpack, just some hack to make it work in node and in browser too.

I can make the "export" part, I don't know if there is any hack to make the "import/require" part.

Comment: Here's how to use `import` / `export` with node: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436580/5734311 and here's how to use it in a browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211891/import-functions-from-another-js-file-javascript/48212558#48212558

Comment: Node supports ESM modules with the [`--experimental-modules`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) flag in node 12 LTS.