# Use External File in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, vue.js

How can I use the content of a file in JavaScript as does VueJS with .vue files? As far as I am aware Vue doesn't use any Ajax to achieve this. So if I have a .whatever file how can I import / parse this external content?

Comment: just add that external file reference in .html and use access the functions, objects from your .js file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211891/import-functions-from-another-js-file-javascript

Comment: Could you code a tiny example?

Comment: Does this work without a server running?