# The requested module does not provide an export named, webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm writing a module with typescript, then I used webpack 5 to convert it to js.
My ES module is very simple
`my.module.ts` is the following:

```js
export class SampleModule {
  constructor(element: Element) {
    this.el = element;
  }

  private el: Element;

  logElement(): void {
    console.log(this.el);
  }
}
```

Generated js via webpack 5

```js
(()=>{"use strict";!function(){function t(t){this.el=t}t.prototype.logElement=function(){console.log(this.el)}}()})();
```

When I want to use it:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
  <script type="module" src="sample1.js"></script>
</body>
```

samle1.js

```js
import { SampleModule } from '../dist/sample.js'
new SampleModule(document.querySelector('[data-name="dtp1"]'));
```

But I get the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../dist/sample.js' does not provide an export named 'SampleModule'
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'sample': './src/sample.ts'    
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /.s?css$/,
      use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {}
        },
        'css-loader'
      ],
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  externals: {
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true
  },
  watch: false,
  devServer: {
    lazy: false,
    watchContentBase: true
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
      }),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: `
version : 4.0.0
      `
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: did you try export default class SampleModule?

Comment: I don't think you can use webpack in this way; you're supposed to have a bunch of modules with import and export statements, then you use webpack on them to create a single script. As you can see in the generated output there's no `SampleModule` anywhere to be seen. In other words, you would have to include `sample1.js` in the webpack operation for this to work.

Comment: My module is written in `typescript`, So I have to convert it via `ts` not webpack! @ChrisG

Comment: I don't understand. Your question says `then I used webpack 5 to convert it to js.`

Comment: I converted my typescript file via webpack 5 not `ts` command directly, I added my webpack config.

Comment: Again: webpack is not the right tool here. Again: webpack is used to compile a bunch of modules into a single script. What you want to do instead is to use modules in the browser, something that wasn't possible until recently (which is why webpack was created). However you can now use `import` and `export` in the browser. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212558/5734311 To be clear: *you cannot do both*.

Answer (score 2):

After some googling I could resolve the problem:
notice to the following part:

```js
module: {
 rules:[
 .
 .
 .
   use: [{
     loader: 'expose-loader',
     options: {
      exposes: ['myNameSpace'],
     },
    }, {
      loader: 'ts-loader'
    }]
 .
 .
 .
 ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js` completely:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'sample': './src/sample.ts'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: {
          exposes: ['myNameSpace'],
        },
      }, {
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /.s?css$/,
      use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {}
        },
        'css-loader'
      ],
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  externals: {
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true
  },
  watch: false,
  devServer: {
    lazy: false,
    watchContentBase: true
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
      }),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: `
version : 4.0.0
      `
    })
  ]
};
```

Now we could use bundled javascript file as follows:

adding javascript to html:

```html
<script src="sample1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

javascript file:

```js
new myNameSpace.SampleModule(document.querySelector('[data-name="dtp1"]'));
```

Comment: @Dayyan this namespace work-around is good, but have you found whether it's possible to use export keyword? and use `import ... from ... bundle.js`?