# How to parse an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is my array which I need to parse, as I am parsing array it is showing me `undefined` in console.

```
var jsonString = {
    "results": [{
        "cc_emails": [
            "test@test.com",
            "test1@test.com",
            "tst2@tst2.com"
        ],
        "name": "test",
        "email": "testemail",
        "email_config_id": 14000037621,
        "priority": 2,
        "product_id": null,
        "created_at": "2021-10-05T22:01:17Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-05T22:05:05Z"

    }]
}
```

I need to correct the above error and show `priority`. Here is my code which consists of `forEach()` loop with which I was iterating the array.

```
// I used foreach here.
$.each(jsonString, function (index, val) 
{
    alert jsonString[index].priority;  
});
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with JSON, those are normal javascript objects

Comment: also, `alert jsonString[index].priority;` is not valid javascript, it should be `alert (jsonString[index].priority);` which you can reduce to just `alert(val.priority)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `jsonString` is an object that contains an array `results`.
You need to apply `forEach` on the result instead of the object.

```js
var jsonString = {
    "results": [{
        "cc_emails": [
            "test@test.com",
            "test1@test.com",
            "tst2@tst2.com"
        ],
        "name": "test",
        "email": "testemail",
        "email_config_id": 14000037621,
        "priority": 2,
        "product_id": null,
        "created_at": "2021-10-05T22:01:17Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-05T22:05:05Z"

    }]
}

jsonString.results.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.priority)
})
```

Comment: Hi i need to return above array by my function and that function i need to access into another js file so how i can do that

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211891/import-functions-from-another-js-file-javascript/48212558

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.results` property here

```js
jsonString.results.forEach(result => {
  console.log(result.priority); // prints priority in console
});
```

if you need to have a priorities array you can use

```js
let priorities = jsonString.results.map(result => {
  return result.priority;
});
```

Comment: With modern javascript you can also avoid callback by using `for (const result of jsonString.results)` loop

Comment: Hi i need to return above array by my function and that function i need to access into another js file so how i can do that

Answer (score 0):

With modern javascript you also can do it this way:

```js
for (const result of jsonString.results) {
  console.log(result.priority);
}
```

[for..of loop documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: Hi i need to return above array by my function and that function i need to access into another js file so how i can do that