# JS function loaded from separate file

Tags: javascript

This simple functions are loaded properly when loaded directly from HTML:

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
</script>
```

But when I try to load it from external .js file the function is not working.
My folder structure looks like below:

```
src
 |--modules
 |   |---- OverlayNav.js
 |
 |--index.js
```

OverlayNav.js

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
        
function closeNav() {
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

index.js

```
import OverlayNav from './modules/OverlayNav'
```

Open Button:

```
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Close Button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```

I'm developing my first custom theme using Node.js and wp-scripts to bundle all my files locally and that's my .json file:

```
{
  "name": "MyTheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "dev": "wp-scripts start",
    "devFast": "wp-scripts start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "*",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212558/9636400

Comment: How do you use the module in the HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import functions from another js file. Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211891/import-functions-from-another-js-file-javascript)

Comment: No, sorry this is small setup for WordPress theme development, Node.js and wp-scrpts to bundle all my files. All modules and other .js are imported and exported nicely but all .js is wrapped within the class. I have tried to export and import in traditional way but this is not working for those stand alone functions

Comment: Please do not add the solution to the question. Please may you remove it and write your own answer?

Comment: Ok, I removed the solution but, I'm not able to add the answer here due to low number of points on my account

Answer (score 0):

## No exports

You haven't [`export`ed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) anything from OverlayNav.js so there is nothing to import.

```
export function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
        
export function closeNav() {
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

## Default import

You have two functions in the file, but are only importing one thing. I used named exports above so you need to use named imports.

```
import { openName, closeName { from ...
```

## URL

Unless you are using a bundler (like Webpack) which can do Node.js-style path resolution, you've also put the wrong URL to the module (the `.js` is missing from the end).

## Globals

When you import a variable into *index.js* it becomes a local variable in the *index.js* module.

It doesn't become a global. (Globals are messy and lead to mistakes).

Don't use `onclick` attributes in the HTML (they have drawbacks beyond depending on globals). Use `addEventListener` in *index.js*.

Comment: thanks yes I'm using node to bundle my files. Please see my .json config I added to the post above. This is just basic config for WorPress I'm only starting just trying my best:(

Comment: Ok so my import is now like this: `import { openNav, closeNav } from './modules/OverlayNav'` added `export` to the functions but still not working

Comment: How can you tell it isn't working?

Comment: Because the overlay is not opening and console shows me this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: openNav is not defined
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick` I also added the my button to the post which is working fine when function is placed within <script> tags and loaded directly from HTML file

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to assign `openNav` to `onclick` somewhere that isn't in the JS file you are `import`ing `openNav` into.

Comment: Re edit. Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: I've added another section to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in my lack of knowledge. I have wrapped all this functions in the class creating constructor, events and methods, then exported as usually and all works just beautiful. Thank you so mych I was loosing my hope in this community as all my posts are always down voted but finally I get some response and that was the best response I ever get here. I will post my function answering my question.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post my final piece of code here as I'm banned from answering the post due to low feedback score on my account :( This is bad because someone could potentially make use of this.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple answer:

use type module to allow imports and export the functions you need from the OverlayNav

```
<script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
```

### Long answer:

You need to bundle file together. This can be achieved with the special tools like [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) or webpack.

Example:

```
npm i parcel
```

```
npx parcel ./src/index.html
```

Comment: Yes I added this to the post as forgot to mention. I'm using Node.js to bundle my files and using wp-scripts. All other .js files are exporting properly but they are wrapped in the classes.

Comment: @Maryando why didn't you export the files?

Comment: because I didn't know how to do it with standard functions I have all other functions wrapped within the class so I was exporting the classes usually. As @Quentin below told me I already added `export` to the functions and imported properly but still no luck. I have also updated the post showing the closeNav and openNav buttons.

Comment: Oh, now I see. With the ES modules you are not able to reference functions or variables directly. Consider using `document.getElementById('MYID').addEventListener('click', YOUR_FUNCTION)

Comment: yes, thanks so much, I'm just starting creating my first functions and basically learning but I finally get this overlay to work!