# Why isn't my import & export working with my JS files

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

So I'm starting with import and export in JS, but I don't understand why my code isn't working.

This is my HTML file:

```
<body>
    <button id="changecolor"></button>
    <script type="module" src="./JSWebTesting.js"> </script>
</body>
```

This is my JSWebTesting file:

```
"use strict";

import { toColor } from './JSWebTesting2.js';

document.getElementById('changecolor').addEventListener('click', () => {
    toColor('green');
})
```

This is my JSWebTesting2 file:

```
"use strict";

function toColor(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

export { toColor }
```

No error message comes up, and I put console.logs into both JS files, but nothing came up in console. I don't understand what is going wrong with my code.

Comment: Click the tiny, empty button at the very top left, then press a key. You will find your code works perfectly fine, you're just using a very weird setup to trigger the color change.

Comment: oh well I forgot I made it trigger on the keydown event. With that though, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You sure you're not getting a CORS warning or something?

Comment: Are you running this on Chrome in a file:/// environment perhaps? [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212558/5734311)

Comment: `"use strict";` is unnecessary in modules, they're strict code implicitly

Comment: Without an error message, we can't really help you.

Comment: I'm just doing "run and debug" on VSCode with the chrome environment. When I click on the link, file:/// pops up so, yes I believe I am. Do modules not really work this way?

Comment: No error message shows up; I'll add that to the post.

Comment: Where do you expect an error message to "pop up"? Are you using the browser devtools? Does "run and debug" work with other projects (using scripts instead of modules)? Are you getting error messages there if you make a mistake?

Comment: I'm just using Visual Studio Code, and usually error messages do pop up.

Comment: The problem isn't a syntax error. Look at the console and you will see the problem: `Access to script at 'file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/.../zdu/JSWebTesting.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.` Like I said, you need Firefox or a local server to use modules like this.

Comment: @ZDu. One of the quickest ways is [with Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project). `yarn create vite`, then `cd [folder]`, then `yarn install`, then `yarn run dev`. Navigate to `localhost:3000`.