# Can't access javascript function from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that automates some tasks on my company's internal website. The website uses .aspx files. I'm trying to call a function `__doPostBack()` from my extension but I get this error:

> test.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined

test.js:

```
function clickLink() {
  __doPostBack('ctl00$Main$AssetSearchPanel$DialogContainers$GridContainers$ctl02$BtnName','')
}

clickLink()
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Containers v2",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "test.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://url.com"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';"
  }
}
```

I tried circumventing calling this function by using inline scripting, but I couldn't because of Chrome security policy.

I'm able to call the function from the Chrome DevTools console of the page.

Comment: Even your content script runs in a different context, you'd have to inject a script into the DOM (assuming your website doesn't have a CSP header which blocks it) which communicates via postMessage to your content script

Comment: Where is the function `__doPostBack` called from?

Comment: My content script test.js

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, you can try the following steps:

- In the `test.js` file, make sure to call the `__doPostBack` function correctly by ensuring that this function matches the URL specified in the `manifest.json` file. Currently, it seems to match only with `https://url.com`, so check that this URL is compatible with the target page.
- If the issue persists, you can update the `content_scripts` section in the `manifest.json` file for the `test.js` file as follows:

  ```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "test.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*.url.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
  ```

  This will match with all pages under `url.com`, including subdomains.
- Due to Chrome's security policy, instead of directly calling functions inside, you can communicate through a message. Add the following code to the `test.js` file:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.action == "callDoPostBack") {
        __doPostBack(request.params);
      }
    }
  );
  ```

  Then, in the file injecting the content, you can call it like this:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "callDoPostBack", params: ['ctl00$Main$AssetSearchPanel$DialogContainers$GridContainers$ctl02$BtnName', '']});
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer on JavaScript knowledge, and this may not be the case on chrome extensions API or whatever it is called.

Most of the time, when calling a function from a different file you would have to import or reference the file in your code.

```
export function __doPostBack() {
// Your code here
```

};

This is the code you would put in script.js to export your function, and to make it able to be accessible by other files.

```
import { __doPostBack } from './script.js';
```

This is the code you would put in test.js to import the functions into your file, and to be able to use it

```
var test = new __doPostBack()
```

Also, you may be able to import your script.js as a library.
In this case:

```
myLibrary.__doPostBack()
```

References:
[import function from another JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211891/import-functions-from-another-js-file-javascript)

Note: If there is an answer of someone actually knowing Google chrome extensions, please use their answer.

Hope this helped you!